# combining multiple outputs in one line in a function

Tags: bash, scripting, output

im trying to build a function or script that reads urls from a file line by line and tests for the status code of the corresponding curl call.

the call in general works fine, but i fail in 2 things:

- the last URL from the textfile gets ignored.
- i won't manage to ouput the status code with the url in one line, ideally tab-separated

the infile p.e. looks like this:

```
https://facebook.com
https://google.com
https://stackoverflow.com
```

the first echo only outputs the $line (url from file) including a blank space - instead of the status code + the url
the second echo outputs the status code allright
the third echo outputs the url ($line) allright.

How do I combine them in one line only?

I tried putting the echo values in brackets (round, curly...)
I tried replacing line breaks with the tr command and sed

```
testredirects() {

if test -f "$1"; then

while IFS= read -r line; do
     output=$(curl -Is $line | head -1 ) 
     echo $output $line
     echo $output
     echo $line
done < "$1"

fi
}
```

the output i am looking for is something like

```
HTTP/2 301 Moved permanently ; https://google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol uses `\r\n` to separate lines, but head doesn't know that and it keeps the `\r`.

Use:

```
output=$(curl -Is https://google.com | head -1 | tr -d "\r")
```

to remove the `\r`

Alternatively, you can use dos2unix to change the line endings:

```
output=$(curl -Is https://google.com | dos2unix | head -1)
```